# Getting message like "The following controls were successfully added to the toolbox but are not enabled in the active designer"

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, editor

I'm trying to add PDF X Change Editor in my Webform in ASP.NET Webpage, I'm using visual studio 2015 version 4.8, and PDF X Change editor version is 1.0, I have added in COM compentents and got as above message, in tool box it's not visible

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Those controls are for desktop applications - not asp.net web based applications. So you can't use desktop ActiveX or COM controls for web based development. Try creating a desktop project - you find + see that you can use that library - but for web based projects, they should and would be disabled.

Comment: thank you, Can suggest any web-based pdf editors so that i can implement in my project

Comment: hum, not off the the top of my head - but any tool will have to be for asp.net - not just .net and desktop

Comment: Thanks for the response